# Selenium webdriver with C# - Restarting the machine and conitnuing testing

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have recently encountered the following scenario which needs to be automated using Selenium WebDriver with C#.

- Step 1: Select a file and write some text in that file.
- Step 2: Restart the machine.
- Step 3: Select the same file and read the text.

Here I can proceed until **step 2**, but once I restart the machine how can I continue to do **step 3**?
Can anyone please give me an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to run your program at system startup, after the reboot. Two ways of achieving this are:

1. Use one of the Run/RunOnce/RunServices/RunServicesOnce registry keys. RunOnce/RunServicesOnes will automatically make sure that your program is [started only once](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/run-program-only-once-when-windows-is-booted-up/), not on every system startup.
2. Create a job in task scheduler that is [triggered on System Startup](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html). You will have to make sure that this job is removed after the program is started, to avoid running on every boot.

You will also need some way in your program to recognize, if it should go to step 1. or 3. This can be easily achieved by writing the state (i.e. next step number) to a file and reading it on application start.

One more thing to consider is if your program can be run without user being logged in (otherwise it isn't fully automated - if you need to wait for user interaction before continuing).

Answer (score -1):

IMO the best course of action is wherever the program stops/errors you comment out the previous code to the beginning (of course you leave the code where you instantiate your browser & navigate to your site)

Comment: I do not see how this would answer the question - and if at all, this should be a comment, not an *answer*.